# Why do CNNs with ReLU learn that well?

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, gradient-descent

Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs) use almost always the rectified linear activation function (ReLU):

$$f(x) = max(0, x)$$

However, the derivative of this function is

$$f'(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } x \leq 0\\ 1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

(ignoring that is not differentiable at $0$, as I think it is done in practice). For inputs > 0 this is fine, but **why doesn't it matter that the gradient is 0 at every point < 0?** Or does it matter? (Are there publications about this problem?)

If a neuron outputs 0 for every sample of the training data, it is basically lost, correct? Its weights will never be adjusted again?

Answer (score 3):

> ignoring that is not differentiable at 00, as I think it is done in practice

yes see  [ReLUs are not differentiable at zero](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222541/12359)

> If a neuron outputs 0 for every sample of the training data, it is basically lost, correct? Its weights will never be adjusted again?

yes see [What is the "dying ReLU" problem in neural networks?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/5706/843)

Comment: While I appreciate the links, you didn't answer my main question. (So only +1 and not accept)