# Bias of 1 in fully connected layers introduced dying relu problem

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolution, convolutional-neural-network, bias

While implementing [AlexNet](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf) ([model-code](https://github.com/paniabhisek/AlexNet/blob/master/model.py)), one of the thing I need to do was to initialize the biases of the convolutional layers and fully connected layers.

Normally we initialize biases with 0s, but the paper says:

> We initialized the neuron biases in the second, fourth, and fifth convolutional layers,
>   as well as in the fully-connected hidden layers, with the constant 1.

So I went ahead and initialized the biases to 1 as the paper says. But that didn't make the network learn at all. Basically the last fully connected layer was producing a lot of 0s, which is otherwise known as [dying-relu-problem](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks). Out of 4096 neurons only 40 or 50 were producing non-zeros.

After lot of debugging, I came to realize that: if I make the fully connected layers' bias to 0 than they are nicely learning. loss decreased nicely.

Now I'm wondering:

- How bias plays the role for *dying-relu-problem* here ?
- Can all *dying-relu-problem* be corrected using bias searching ?